# How to rebuild a panel

Tags: wxpython

In my **init** I have this:

```
def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,self.title,size=wx.DisplaySize())
    self.newpanel=wx.Panel(self,size=wx.DisplaySize())
```

and there is a function which shall destroy the Panel "newpanel" and rebuild it (and putting some buttons etc. in it):

```
def newpanelbuild(self,event):
    self.newpanel.Destroy()
    self.newpanel=wx.Panel(self,size=wx.DisplaySize())
    # creating some wx.Buttons, wx.TextCtrl's & wx.Choice
```

When I run my program, I don't get an error and when the event for "newpanelbuild" is activated, the correct panel is shown - but I can't click the buttons, textctrl & dropdowns in it... it looks like the panel is in the background / doesn't have the focus. So I tried adding "self.newpanel.SetFocus()" but it didn't helped. How can I solve this?

Edit:
I just combined all my little questions to one big question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604139/need-tutorial-for-menubar-handling-panel-building

Answer (score 0):

Why are you destroying the panel? You can just add the widgets to the original panel. What I would do is put the widgets that can change into a sizer and then just destroy the sizer or the sizer's children. You might also be interested in this tutorial on panel switching:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/

Comment: Tahnks! But I just combined all my little questions to one big question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604139/need-tutorial-for-menubar-handling-panel-building